# Why is part of my code not executed?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, cinema-4d

I'm using Visual C++ to compile my plug-in for Cinema 4D.

```
    GeDebugOut("-->");
    subroot = NULL;
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    success = PolygonizeHierarchy(source, hh, head, tail, &subroot, malloc);
    if (!success) {
        /* .. */
    }
    String str("not set.");
    if (subroot) {
        GeDebugOut("yes");
        str = "yes!";
        GeDebugOut("Subroot name: " + subroot->GetName());
    }
    else {
        GeDebugOut("no");
        str = "no!";
    }
    GeDebugOut("Is there a subroot?   " + str);
    GeDebugOut("<--");
```

The expected output is the following:

```
-->
yes
Subroot name: Cube
Is there a subroot?  yes
<--
```

(or the same with "no" instead.) But I get

```
-->
yes
<--
```

**Why are two prints missing here?**

---

This is the declaration of `GeDebugOut`.

```
void GeDebugOut(const CHAR* s,  ...);
void GeDebugOut(const String& s);
```

The `String` class is concatenateable. It overloads the `+` operator.

```
String(void);
String(const String& cs);
String(const UWORD* s);
String(const CHAR* cstr, STRINGENCODING type = STRINGENCODING_XBIT);
String(LONG count, UWORD fillch);
friend const String operator +(const String& Str1, const String& Str2);
const String& operator +=(const String& Str);
```

Comment: How is `GeDebugOut` declared?

Comment: Is `String` a typedef for `std::string`?

Comment: It looks like the overload of `GeDebugOut` for `String` isn't working properly. Have you tested that?

Comment: @NiklasR: I think Unicode is enabled. In that case, you need to use `L"string literal"`. See my answer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Omg.. How did you find out? I would never have had that idea, lol.. I can do `GeDebugOut("foobar")` and it works fine. But `GeDebugOut(String("foobar"))` doesn't print anything. Sorry to everyone and thanks for their answers. :D

Comment: @NiklasR: In that case, the workaround is just, as I said, use `%s` like you use in `printf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `GeDebugOut` like you use `printf`:

```
GeDebugOut("Some message =  %s ", whatever);
```

where `whatever` is a c-string, i.e its type is `char*`.

Since an overload of `GeDebugOut` accepts `String` type also, then I think you need to use unicode as:

```
GeDebugOut(L"Is there a subroot?   " + str);
        // ^ note this!
```

because *my suspicion* is that if unicode is enabled, then `CHAR` is basically `wchar_t`, not `char`. And because of this, the string concatenation doesn't work, as the string-literal doesn't implicitly get converted into `String` type, to be passed to `+` overload.

Comment: Oh, good to know. But the application crashes now, I guess because it expects `char*` and I pass String. But the `String` class is concatenateable, so why shouldn't it work this way?

Comment: Please also see my edit which includes the declaration of `GeDebugOut`

Comment: @NiklasR: `whatever` should be a c-string.

Comment: You have GeDebugOut() takes in `char*`,  When you pass it the string literal, it chooses that one, so your `+` is doing pointer arithmetic instead of string concatenation, especially if `String` has a conversion to `char*`.

Comment: @JohnMcG: You'd only get pointer arithmetic here if `String` had a conversion to a numeric type. You can't add two pointers, so a conversion to `char*` wouldn't be considered.

Comment: This sample program:int
main()
{
  char* p1, p2;
  char* p3 = p1 + p2;
  return 0;
}
compiles in gcc.

Comment: @JohnMcG: `p2` is `char`, not `char*`. Try this : `char *p1, *p2; char* p3 = p1 + p2;`

Comment: @Nawaz Yup, did another one with conversion operators that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append a string to a string literal.

`"Is there a subroot"` is a string literal and the compiler will see the use of it as a pointer to that literal.

A better way would be to do:

```
GeDebugOut("Is there a subroot? %s ", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there are two versions of `GeDebugOut` the compiler can choose from:

```
void GeDebugOut(const CHAR* s,  ...);
void GeDebugOut(const String& s);
```

when it encounters:

```
GeDebugOut("Is there a subroot?   " + str);
```

`"Is there a subroot"` is a string literal, which translates to type `const char*`.  I suspect `String` has a conversion operator to some numeric type.  So the compiler is choosing the first overload.

This is resulting in behavior you're not expecting, because the `+` operation for `const char*` is pointer arithmetic, not string concatenation, so you're calling `GeDebugOut` on the pointer sum of your string literal, and whatever the output of that `const char*` conversion of `str` is.

There's several ways you can correct this.  As another mentioned, you can change it to `printf`-like syntax.  Or you can  force it to use the `String` overlaod like so:

```
GeDebugOut(String("Is there a subroot?") + str);
```

Comment: Edited to note after being corrected that compiler will not allow arithmetic between pointer variables, though it seems less likely that `String` would be convertable to a numeric type, so my suspicion seems less valid.